# stop timer at 0 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

i set a setinterval starting from 20 to 0. When the counter is smaller than or equal 10 i want the text to change to red (this works) but when it reaches 0 i want the counter to stop decreasing, but it doesn't. what am i doing wrong?

```
`let timerCount = document.querySelector('.imposters__voting span')
let counter = 20; 
setInterval(function(){
    if (counter > 11){
        counter--; 
    } else if(counter <= 10){
        counter--;
        document.querySelector('.imposters__voting').style.color = 'red'
    } else if(counter = 0){
        document.querySelector('.imposters__voting').style.color = 'red'
        document.querySelector('.imposters__voting').innerText = 'Voting has ended'
    }
    timerCount.innerText = counter

}, 1000)`
```

I tried counter = 0 but it didnt work

Comment: _**1st**_ due to `if (counter > 11) { ... } else if (counter <= 10) { ... }` there are already two conditions where always either does match. Thus even a properly written third clause like `if (counter ` **`===`** `0) { ... }` will never be reached. Thus _**2nd**_ though the OP can write `(counter ` **`=`** `0)` and it is a valid expression this expression does not compare `counter` to zero but assigns the zero value to `counter`.

Answer (score 3):

`else if(counter = 0)` will never be executed, because `else if(counter <= 10)` is true for all values lower than 10.

Your if statements should look like this:

```
if(counter == 0) {}
else if(counter > 10) {}
else if(counter <= 10) {}
```

Also make sure to clear the interval in the first if statement: `clearInterval(interval)`.

Comment: It should be >= 11, otherwise it will stop at 11.

Comment: I just copied the rules from the question. But you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the order of your if statements is wrong. For example, when using `counter <= 11` before `counter <= 1`, the first statement will always be true for values lower than 11 and the second statement will not be reached.

Secondly, you should use `counter == 0` instead. This will check if the value is 0 and not set it to 0.

Lastly, it's recommended to stop your interval using `clearInterval()`.

```js
const timer = document.querySelector('.imposters__voting');
const timerCount = document.querySelector('.imposters__voting span');
let counter = 19;
let interval = setInterval(function() {
    timerCount.innerText = counter;
    if (counter > 10) {
        counter--;
    } else if (counter <= 0) {
        timer.innerText = 'Voting has ended';
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else if (counter <= 10) {
        counter--;
        timer.style.color = 'red';
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="imposters__voting">
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that my answer will set the text in the span to 20 in the first loop, so it will start after one second with the countdown. If you don't want that, start with `let counter = 19;` instead.

Comment: I would change `let counter = 20;` to `let counter = 19;`. `setInterval` will wait 1 second and after that interval you set 20 in den `span`. So there are 2 seconds before 19 will be shown.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `clearInterval()` method when you want to stop the interval code from running again. To do so, you need to capture the ID of that interval in a variable:

```
let intervalId = setInterval(function(){})
```

when you want to stop it from running again

```
clearInterval(intervalId)
```